# Updated a MySQL table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This seems so easy.  My code checks out, and even if I run the resetting fuction in phpMyAdmin it works, but for some reason the table never updates when I run the php.

```
<?php 
$servername="localhost" ; 
$username="***" ; 
$password="***" ; 
$dbname="***" ; 
$conn=new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
if ($conn->connect_error) { 
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); 
} 
$sql = "SELECT `Alert` FROM `poonpad_daveAlert` WHERE 1"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql); 
if ($result == 1) {
    echo "wow, stuff is happening. resetting."; resetting();
} else { 
    echo "this place is dead";
} 

function resetting() { 
    $sql = "UPDATE `poonpad_daveAlert` SET `Alert`=2 WHERE 1";
}

$conn->close(); 
?>
```

Comment: you want update all the rows?

Comment: You don't execute the query in the function. Also I see a variable scope issue

Comment: i can't see where you executed your update query

Comment: Please indent your control blocks.

Comment: What are you trying to test with ```$result == 1```? Also, the where clause in your select is unneeded if you want to select all rows. Same for the update statement, the where doesn't mean anything and will select all rows. Also, you never execute the update statement.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd use the below to execute the query.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Second, instead of (result==1) which I'm not sure is intended for what purpose, you should use (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0).

Third, for the resetting function, I think you need to mention the column name for the WHERE condition which you set to 1 as well as the main $sql query, and you don't need the WHERE if you have to select all rows.

```
"UPDATE `poonpad_daveAlert` SET `Alert`=2 WHERE [column-name]=1";
```